# Compute $E(M_\sigma)$ and $E(e^{-\sigma})$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, martingales, stopping-times

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Standard Brownian Motion and $(M_t)_{t\geq 0}$ the martingale defined by
$$
M_t = B_t + e^{\sqrt{2}B_t - t},\quad t\geq 0.
$$
I have to compute $E(M_\sigma)$ and $E(e^{-\sigma})$ where
$$
\sigma = \inf\{t\geq 0: B_t = 1\}
$$

My idea is to use Optional Sampling Theorem for the first one, but I do not know if what I done to see integrability is okay (I said that $E|M_{t\wedge \sigma}| \leq 1 + e^{\sqrt{2}}$... it sounds weird. Maybe Doob's inequality is fine?). On the other hand, I have no intuition to calculating $Ee^{-\sigma}$. Any hint, please?

Comment: What do you mean that you "already checked" the martingale?

Comment: that I have already checked that it is a martingale

Comment: For the second expectation you can apply the optional stopping theorem to the exponential martingale stopped martingale $N_{t\land \sigma}$ where $N_t=\exp(\sqrt{2} B_t- t)$. For the first one I'm not sure.

Comment: it's true! thank you very much